# How can I count the number of rows that meet multiple criteria on python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the number of rows in a dataframe where the value of two columns in the dataframe equal to 'clear'. The code I have is:

```py
pass_both_checks = len(merged_outer(([merged_outer['result_x'] == 'clear']) & [merged_outer['result_y'] == 'clear']))
```

where 'merged_outer' is the dataframe and I want the result to be the count of all rows where column 'result_x' and column 'result_y' equals 'clear'.

However, I am getting an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'

How do I fix this? If I insert just one condition in the code for pass_both_checks, it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Seon: well in pandas `&` is used as the vectorized `and`

Answer (score 6):

For filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) add `()` around conditions:

```
pass_both_checks = len(merged_outer[(merged_outer['result_x'] == 'clear') & 
                                    (merged_outer['result_y'] == 'clear')])
```

Or use `sum` for count `True`s:

```
pass_both_checks = ((merged_outer['result_x'] == 'clear') & 
                    (merged_outer['result_y'] == 'clear')).sum()
```

Or compare both columns and test if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
pass_both_checks = (merged_outer[['result_x', 'result_y']] == 'clear').all(axis=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a syntax problem, you have to replace few parentheses with brackets as following :

```
pass_both_checks = len(merged_outer.loc[(merged_outer['result_x'] == 'clear']) & (merged_outer['result_y'] == 'clear')])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get row wise check then get only the `True`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'clear'], ['b', 'c'], ['clear', 'clear'], ['clear', 'clear']], columns=['A', 'B'])

(df[['A', 'B']]=='clear').all(axis=1).value_counts()[True] #2
```